# Service getting killed even if the app is in Background

Tags: java, android, service

I am using a Service for performing some task, which should run only if the app is in background, moreover the service runs for sometime and after sometime, it gets destroyed. Earlier this was working completely fine, but don't know where i am doing wrong.

Here is the code of my Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    Context context;
    public static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
        context = applicationContext;
        Log.i("myservice", "here service created!");
    }

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[onCreateService]");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        // Code
        registerOverlayReceiver();
        context = this;
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterOverlayReceiver();
        Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void unregisterOverlayReceiver() {
        if (myReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        }
    }

    private static final String ACTION_DEBUG = "abc.action.DEBUG";

    private void registerOverlayReceiver() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_DEBUG);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "[onReceive]" + action);
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                showMyActivity();
            } else if (action.equals(ACTION_DEBUG)) {
                showMyActivity();
            }
        }
    };

    private void showMyActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

I have debugged but couldn't find out the problem for the same.
Anybody who came across anything like this can help me out.

Comment: Background services get killed after a while. That's just how it is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52552450/how-to-start-a-background-service-in-oreo

Comment: What id the android version you are using?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, is there a way to get it started, everytime it is being destroyed?

Comment: What is the task you need to perform? There might be better ways to do that then Service... Services are most likely killed by Android due to battery saving policy. Moreover every phone manufacturer has its own ways to kill your background services...